# How to make Toast show at the TOP?

Tags: android, toast, gravity

I can't get my Toast to show at the TOP.

The following code is still printing the toast at the bottom. Am I doing something wrong?

```
falseButton.setOnClickListener { view: View ->
            val toast = Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Incorrect",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0)
                toast.show()

        }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: .setGravity() does not work anymore. [Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#setGravity(int,%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 1):

```
Toast mytoast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast Message", 1);  
mytoast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);                  
mytoast.show();
```

This should work for the current activity.